# Consequences of university losing its accreditation on admission for further graduate education?

Tags: graduate-admissions, accreditation

I graduated 10 years ago from a school that just lost its accreditation.

What kind of consequences can I expect from this?

In particular about that affecting admission chances for further education. Although my university wasn’t a top one, I though that my 4.0 GPA would allow me, in the future, to do a top PhD program.

But now my former school is closing down. There are, so far, no plans to try to resurrect it or reapply for accreditation. It will just cease to exist and transcripts are handled by another institution.

Do you know similar cases or have specific evidence on the matter?

Comment: Why would something that happens to a school after you graduate affect the worth of your degree?  Also, your question about how this affects future job applications (which I guess is essentially not at all) is not a fit for this site (see Workplace.SE).

Comment: @Kimball "Why would something that happens to a school after you graduate affect the worth of your degree?" Well, suppose that the university you attended was subsequently revealed to be a fradulent sham, after you graduated. That would clearly affect the worth of your degree. It seems reasonable, to me, to ask "Hey, the university that awarded me a business degree just failed as a business. Will that affect what people think of my degree?"

Comment: @DavidRicherby to be fair, business professors are not usually the ones running the university.

Comment: Your school may have already had a grading problem if you went from "average undistinguished" at UCLA to "top 1%er" there without a major change in e.g. your own study habits. I suggest documenting what you have done during self-employment, and working on letters of recommendation from clients.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Huh? I have "average undistinguished" height in the UK but, if I went to various places in the world, I would be noticeably tall. That doesn't mean that those other places have a height-measuring problem; it just means I've moved into a different demographic.

Answer (score 4):

"**If I look for a job in the future i would be applying mostly on my degree’s strength and grades and with references from former teachers**."

I think that approach is completely incorrect. You need to focus much more on the fact that you have 10 years of experience as an entrepreneur. Employers will want to know what you've accomplished in 10 years. They will want to know why you decided to "go it alone". The will want to know if you are "gutsy" enough to work for them in a challenging capacity.

When they ask you where your degree is from, tell them, but you don't have to volunteer that the institution is winking out of existence. If they find out on their own, demonstrate to them that you're fully aware of the situation and the reasons for the institution's troubles. Be knowledgeable and non-defeatist. They'll respect that. You're not to blame for the school's fall. You're not the one who went bankrupt.

In the meantime, make sure you get any paperwork from the school that you need. Be proactive about this...not defeatist. This isn't your fault. And for God's sake, don't delve into a pity-party with any potential employer about how you went to a "lower tier" school because you wanted to "stand out". That's completely ridiculous. Trust me. Don't go that route.